# Send PDFs with chatbot dialogflow?

Tags: flutter, dialog

I am currently working on a project in flutter, which includes a chatbot. Now I was wondering if it is possible to send a user a pdf when dialogflow is recognizing a certain Intent.

Example:

User:"pdf" -> Dialogflow recognizes Intent = pdf --> Chat bot sends requested pdf.

I think it´s maybe possible with the help of "Fullfilment". I am quite new to flutter and dialogflow.

I would be grateful for some help!